# MS Access SQL SELECT INTO; Missing Operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So, I'm brand new to VBA, SQL, and MS Access in general. I'm half-expecting to be told that my entire approach is vastly misguided here, but here we go, anyway.

Purpose:
I'm currently trying to print labels through Bartender using Access (People higher than me prefer that over just using the built-in label printing stuff to begin with. Go figure.) One feature of my database that I'd like to incorporate is the ability to double-click the "Label" field on a form and have it automatically print the labels for that specific record only.

Procedure:
My current understanding to do this is to create a temporary table in a separate database that has the information needed for the label, then call Bartender up to pull the info from that database and print the labels.
SO I'm trying to use an SQL SELECT INTO statement to create this new table. Needless to say, it's not working.

Code:

```
        Private Sub Label_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim iID As Integer
    Dim SQL As String

    iID = [ID]

    SQL = "SELECT [ID], [Sign 1], [Sign 2], [Destination 1], [Destination 2], [Label], [Wire #] " & _
                "FROM [WireMaster] WHERE [ID] = " & iID & " " & _
                "INTO TempData (IN G:\OPS\ZShared\PrintData.accdb)"


    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Error:

```
Run-time error '3075':

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID] = 860 INTO
TempData (IN G:\OPS\ZShared\PrintData.accdb)'
```

Random other points of interest:
From what I understand, the "From" and "Into" lines are supposed to be the other way around? Though doing so gives me an error saying I need a query or form in my query. Not having the [] around the fields (ID, Sign 1, etc) gives me another missing operator error.

I'll be able to print it fine once I get the table created, so I'm fixing this problem before adding the print command.

"WireMaster" is a table in my current database
"TempData" is the table I want to create in the PrintData.accdb database

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical syntax for `SELECT INTO` would be:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT [ID],[Sign 1],[Sign 2],[Destination 1],[Destination 2],[Label],[Wire #] INTO TempData IN 'G:\OPS\ZShared\PrintData.accdb' FROM [WireMaster] WHERE [ID]=" & iID
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I put TempData in a different database?

Comment: Now I'm getting an error: "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Comment: And that did it! Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, give this a try. Tell me how it goes

```
SQL = "SELECT * INTO [destination table] FROM (SELECT [ID], [Sign 1], [Sign 2], [Destination 1], [Destination 2], [Label], [Wire #] " & _
                "FROM [WireMaster] WHERE [ID] = " & iID & ";"
```